# Swiper slider fullscreen not exit safari

Tags: javascript, slider, gallery, swiper.js

Swiper slider working well in mac os safari too, but once I click on the enter full screen icon, I cannot exit by click on it again. It continues sliding well in fullscreen, but cannot exit, only with press ESC key.

Does anybody faced to this issue?
Is it a swiper bug? Any idea?

The code nothing special, it uses webkitExitFullscreen in the case of Safari. The method called and it looks great but do nothing.

```
    function _exitFullscreen() {
       if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
       } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
       } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
       }
    }
```

Comment: it would be helpful to provide an example

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The correct function name for WebKit browsers is `webkitCancelFullScreen`, not `webkitExitFullscreen`.